# Add text on image in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am creating barcodes in python using Barcode library like the following:

```
        barcodes = CompanyBarcodes.objects.filter(asn_id__asn_number=asn_id,
                                                  company=company,
                                                  product__asset_category__in=cat_ids
            ).prefetch_related('company', 'product', 'grn_id', 'asn_id', 'itemGroup')

        items = []

        for i in barcodes:
            items.append({'bar': i.barcode, 'name': str(i.product.name)
                          + " - " + str(i.product.sku)})

        alist = []

        for item in items:
            print("item", item)
            EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
            d = {'module_width': 0.15,
                 'module_height': 2.0,
                 'quiet_zone': 0.5,
                 'text_distance': 1.5,
                 'font_size': 3,
                 'text_line_distance': 3,
                 'dpi': 900}
            w = ImageWriter(d)
            ean = EAN(item['bar'], writer=ImageWriter())
            a = ean.save(item['bar'], options=d)
```

Now in the items list we have dictionaries which consists of two parts `bar` and `name`. how can I add the name in the image created by ImageWriter?

I tried:

```
            with open(a, 'rb') as image:
                img = Image.open(image)

                # Create a drawing context on the image
                draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

                # Use the same font as the original barcode image
                font = ImageFont.load_default()

                # Set the font size
                font_size = 10  # You can adjust the font size as needed

                # Calculate the position to center the text
                text = item['name']
                text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(text, font=font)
                image_width, image_height = img.size
                text_x = (image_width - text_width) / 2
                text_y = image_height - text_height - 5  # Adjust the vertical position as needed

                # Draw the text on the image
                draw.text((text_x, text_y), text, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=font)  # You can adjust the fill color

                # Save the modified image
                img.save(a)  # Overwrite the original image with the changes
                encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open(a, 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')
                alist.append({'image': encoded_image, **item})
```

But the text add is way too small and have totally different font from the one in the barcode.

Something like this[image]

Comment: What are the `CompanyBarcodes` and which libraries do we need to use to produce the same result?

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin This the model where the barcodes are stored, along with the product and other info

Comment: Is it possible to get it so that we can try your code and assist you?